# DRF display verbose message in error message for a custom exception handler

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my custom exception handler:

```py
def my_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        error_code = 'unknown'                
        if hasattr(exc, 'default_code') :
            error_code = exc.default_code

        message = ''
        if hasattr(exc, 'default_detail'):
            message = exc.default_detail
                   
        error = {
            "error":response.data,
            "code":error_code,
            'message':message,
        }
        response.data = error

    return response
```

The problem here is whenever I send bad data I get a response like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "email": [
            "Enter a valid email address."
        ],
        "phone_number": [
            "asd is not a valid phone"
        ]
    },
    "code": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid input."
}
```

As you can see the message is just "Invalid input." But I want to get a verbose message here. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this maybe you will get it.!

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler



def get_response(message="", result={}, status=False, status_code=200):
    return {
        "message": message,
        "result": result,
        "status": status,
        "status_code": status_code,
    }




def get_error_message(error_dict):
field = next(iter(error_dict))
response = error_dict[next(iter(error_dict))]
if isinstance(response, dict):
    response = get_error_message(response)
elif isinstance(response, list):
    response_message = response[0]
    if isinstance(response_message, dict):
        response = get_error_message(response_message)
    else:
        response = field + ": " + response[0]
return response


def handle_exception(exc, context):
    error_response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if error_response is not None:
        error = error_response.data

        if isinstance(error, list) and error:
            if isinstance(error[0], dict):
                error_response.data = get_response(
                    message=get_error_message(error),
                    status_code=error_response.status_code,
                )

            elif isinstance(error[0], str):
                error_response.data = get_response(
                    message=error[0],
                    status_code=error_response.status_code
                )

        if isinstance(error, dict):
            error_response.data = get_response(
                message=get_error_message(error),
                status_code=error_response.status_code
            )
    return error_response



class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)

        if response.status_code == 500:
            response = get_response(
                message="Internal server error, please try again later",
                status_code=response.status_code
            )
            return JsonResponse(response, status=response['status_code'])

        if response.status_code == 404 and "Page not found" in str(response.content):
            response = get_response(
                message="Page not found, Something went wrong.",
                status_code=response.status_code
            )
            return JsonResponse(response, status=response['status_code'])

        if response.status_code == 401:
            response = get_response(
                message=response.data['message'],
                status_code=response.status_code
            )
            return JsonResponse(response, status=response['status_code'])

        return response
```

Comment: What is that 'get_response' sir?

Comment: sorry i missed one thing and you got it. that's good.. i edit my answer check it.

Comment: you can ask any query about that.

Comment: Still 'get_error_message' is known

Comment: i edit my answer again please check it out